# "Perception" is to "recognition" as "execution" is to what?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, analogy

I may not be using the right words for this analogy. "Perception" and "execution" are intended to have contrasting meanings.

- By "perception" I mean the reception of data.
- By "recognition" I mean the addition of structure to the perception.
- By "execution" I mean the transformation of data to action.

**What is a (mass?) noun describing the addition of structure to the execution?**

---

Note: I think "acquisition" describes the addition of structure to execution, but not to *the* execution. Similarly, I think "recognition" describes the addition of structure not to perception, but to *the* perception.

Comment: When you assign such arbitrary meanings to the three given terms you really give us no basis for suggesting that any particular randomly-selected term is preferable for your fourth meaning to all other randomly-selected terms.

Comment: I can see a path from *perception* to *recognition*. But once *execution* has happened (and resulted in an action), what more is to be added? I think a similar path would be from *recognition* [of a solution] to *execution* [of that solution]. What could possibly be added to *execution*?

Comment: @StoneyB: It is the other way around: I am assigning words to meanings, not meanings to words. I tried to pick the best three I could find; perhaps "execution" is not a great choice. I want to find the optimal word for the concept I have attempted to elucidate above.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: There are two ways to add structure to "execution": "structured transformation of data to action" and "transformation of structured data to action". I think the former corresponds to "acquisition". In the latter case, the structure is being added before the transformation takes place.

Comment: Well, you might know what you mean, but I have no idea what you're talking about. And, judging by the answers so far, I'm not sure many others do either.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in that series recognition already provides the structure needed to determine what the execution reaction will entail. But perhaps the addition of a ***deliberation*** step provides what you are looking for, in that it separates the reception and recognition of information from the process of deciding one of many possible actions to take based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **strategy**, i.e. methodology to plan/obtain a successful execution.